# Prompt user about pending changes

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a ASP.NET page, where I have couple of editable dropdowns, few editable textboxes and few display only fields.

I want to track whether user changed any dropdown values or textbox values. When user click goBack button, I want to prompt them with a message that the changes are not saved and if they really want to go back.

Please let me know what is the easiest way to track the changes on textbox or dropdwon list.

Thanks

Comment: Session Variables or ViewState you want to also check for IsPostBack and or other State in regards to if the information has been saved or not.. what code can you show in regards to where you want the logic to do this ..? you could also add some JavaScript that will disable the back button..
You may want to add validation as well to make sure that key fields or values have been populated or filled out..

Answer (score 1):

You can add something like this to your page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var submit = false; 
window.onbeforeunload = confirmLeave;


function confirmLeave()
{
        if (!submit)
        {
                return "You have unsaved changes. Are you sure you want to leave the page?";
         }
  }
</script>


<asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit"  OnClientClick="javascript:submit=true;"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add change handlers to all the inputs you want to track.
I would highly recommend [jQuery blur](http://api.jquery.com/blur/) for this.
Blur will be fired whenever a loss of focus occurs occurs on an input or select. If you want to track actual value changes, you could save the value the page loaded with using [jQuery data](http://api.jquery.com/data/)

```
<script>
inputChanged = false;

$('input, select').blur(function() {
    inputChanged = true;
});

window.onbeforeunload = function()
{
    if (inputChanged)
    {
        return "You have unsaved changes. Discard change?";
    }
}
</script>
```